# Does having video at 30fps instead of 29.97fps help performance and/or quality on iPhones?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, frame-rate

Many videos are at 29.97FPS, but would it be better for performance or quality to change them to 30 FPS exactly? That way, it would be a perfect multiple of the iPhone's 60 FPS, and so you wouldn't need any frame interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will take 0.1% less effort to decode the stream, and repeat 0.1% of the frames. But these numbers are below the threshold of human perception, so No.

Comment: How do you know that the iPhone doesn't do frame interpolation instead of repeating frames?